# Angular2 How can I override provider

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and have a question regarding provider overriding. I'd like to use this datepicker in my project https://www.npmjs.com/package/mydatepicker.

I want to override locale provider this library's component uses. Here is example https://plnkr.co/edit/fS8IoJqB8PYvgNEVGIMY.

I extended `LocaleService` from library class (`my.locale.service.ts`) and want to use it instead of it, so I specified it in my module:

```
providers: [{provide: LocaleService, useClass: MyLocaleService }]
```

But it doesn't work, component still uses it's own `LocaleService`. How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this finally work for you? I was struggling with this for some time with no result.

Answer (score 15):

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-two-modules-provide-the-same-service

> What if two modules provide the same service? When two imported
>   modules, loaded at the same time, list a provider with the same token,
>   the second module's provider "wins". That's because both providers are
>   added to the same injector.
>
> When Angular looks to inject a service for that token, it creates and
>   delivers the instance created by the second provider.
>
> Every class that injects this service gets the instance created by the
>   second provider. Even classes declared within the first module get the
>   instance created by the second provider. This can be an unwelcome
>   surprise.
>
> If Module A provides a service for token 'X' and imports a module B
>   that also provides a service for token 'X', then Module A's service
>   definition "wins".
>
> The service provided by the root AppModule takes precedence over
>   services provided by imported modules. The AppModule always wins.

If you provide the provider in `AppModule` this one will be used over providers provided in imported modules.

This is different for lazy loaded modules. If a provider is provided in a lazy loaded module, components and services lazy loaded by this module will get the dependency from the provider of the lazy loaded module, even when it's provided in AppModule as well.

Comment: "two modules provide the same service" is not the challenge here; nor are "Lazy loaded modules". The challenge is module `A` imports module `B` ; module `B` defines component `Bc` ; [component `Bc` provides service `Bs`](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker/blob/master/src/my-date-picker/my-date-picker.component.ts#L32) ; how can module `A` change the implementation of the service provided to the component `Bc`? Apparently changing providers on **modules** , like `A`, will **not** affect / override the providers on **components**, like `Bc`, or even a component `Ac` in the `A` module?

Answer (score 1):

Your paths seem to be imported wrongly and your service file needs to be inside the src directory.

```
import {MyDatePickerModule} from "mydatepicker/dist/my-date-picker.module";
import {LocaleService} from "mydatepicker/dist/services/my-date-picker.locale.service";
import {MyLocaleService} from "./my.locale.service";
```

See below working plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/e63S9dGXSc65BcKWMPnd?p=preview

Comment: Oh, thanks! Fixed my plunker. So now the question is how to replace LocaleService library's component uses with my own.

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me (Angular 7.x):

```
 imports: [ MyCoreModule.forRoot()],
 providers: [{provide: LoginService, useValue: new LoginServiceMock()}]
```

Login service is part of the `MyCoreModule` but I can override it with the mock provider. Also, if you are using `useValue` then don't forget the **new** `yourService()`

```
{ provide: MyService, useValue: new MockMyService1() }
```